# csv files and how to get information from them (in python)

Tags: python, csv

hi i am trying to pull data from a csv file, i am trying to get data from a specific row and column, i need to be able to change what row or column i am pulling data from

eg:

```
column = 3

row = 2


if "example.csv" (column) (row) == "john doe" 
   
print "true"

else:
   print "false"
```

i mostly tried to find this problem online and copy the code
but i would ether get the error list index out of range or it would just print the file in plan text

Comment: It helps to post the code that fails so we can see how far you've gotten.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this dummy data:

```
Param1, Param2, Param3
0, 1, 2
3, 4, 5
6, 7, 8
```

If you run this code on it...

```
import csv

headers = None
with open("dummy_data.csv", 'r') as csv_file:
     reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
     for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if i == 0: # If your data has a header
            headers = row
            print(f"Header names: {headers}")
        else: # The data
            print(f"Row {i} data:")
            for j, col in enumerate(row):
                print(f"Col '{headers[j]}' value: {col}")
```

...you will get this output:

```
Header names: ['Param1', ' Param2', ' Param3']
Row 1 data:
Col 'Param1' value: 0
Col ' Param2' value:  1
Col ' Param3' value:  2
Row 2 data:
Col 'Param1' value: 3
Col ' Param2' value:  4
Col ' Param3' value:  5
Row 3 data:
Col 'Param1' value: 6
Col ' Param2' value:  7
Col ' Param3' value:  8
```

As you can see, you could add conditions in either the row or column loops to do special processing on that particular data element.

Comment: If helpful, consider accepting it as the answer or upvoting it, so's I get my points! :)